# sml match non exhaustive warning

Tags: pattern-matching, sml

i want to make a function that return 0 if the list is empty otherwise 1

and the binding shoul be (  val len = fn : (int * int * int) list list list list -> int )

```
fun len[[[(x:(int*int*int)list)]]]=

if null x then 0 else 1


this code seems working but there is a warning
```

Warning: match nonexhaustive
((x :: nil) :: nil) :: nil => ...

Comment: `[[[[(1,2,3)],[(4,5,6)]]]]` is an example of a value of type  `(int * int * int) list list list list` for which your definition fails.

Comment: `val a = [] ` is an even easier example of a value of the input type for which `len a` fails with `nonexhaustive match failure`. Your definition only accounts for the possibility that the inmost list in empty.

Comment: how can i fix it then can you me some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't clearly specified in all cases when your function should be `0` and when it should be `1`. It is easy enough to get rid of the warning. You could use a `case` expression which is `0` when you want it to be `0` and then be `1` in all other cases. Something like:

```
fun len (nested:(int * int * int) list list list list) = case nested of
      [] => 0
    | [[]] => 0
    | [[[]]] => 0
    | [[[[]]]] => 0
    | _ => 1;
```

Comment: its wotking thankyou i have request how can i access the value of second in (int*int*int) i try |_ => #2 nested it gave me some error

Answer (score 1):

It is warning you, because your function `len` operates on values of type `(int * int * int) list list list list, but only matches values where the innermost level of nested lists contains one or more elements. Asking it to handle *any* other case will result in an exception. Your compiler is just giving you a heads up on this.